# text expand width of column

Tags: html, css

I have quite a problem, than I have tried to solve that last many hours. I cannot understand why my text is aligned left here: [My Example Site](http://roulettesuite.com/backup.html)

The text with the yellow background was also aligned to the left, which I solved with the `.content` class I made.

I tried to set that class on my text again, but it seems like it is not working. I am working in the [foundation framework](https://foundation.zurb.com/emails/docs/alignment.html) for email newsletters.

```css
.bgcolor {
  background-color: #fff;
}
.bgcolor--blue {
  background-color: #ccd8db;
}
.bgcolor--content--light {
  background-color: #ebe4cf;
}
.bgcolor--footer {
  background-color: #e8e8e8;
}
/* Images */

.image--center {
  text-align: center;
}
.image--center__inline {
  display: inline-block;
}
.content {
  padding: 15px;
  max-width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<table class="wrapper" align="center">
  <tr>
    <td class="wrapper-inner">
      <!-- Row 1 -->
      <table class="row collapse bgcolor">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <th class="small-12 large-12 columns first">
              <table>
                <tr>
                  <th class="image--center">
                    <a href="https://www.google.dk/">
                      <img src="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-Z4vZ7AsD6Bc/T_PNRK_9f2I/AAAAAAAAAH4/t3UZ3BQyqdE/s1600/shutterstock.jpg" alt="test" align="center" class="float-center image--center__inline">
                    </a>
                  </th>
                  <th class="expander"></th>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </th>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <!-- Row 2 -->
      <table class="row collapse bgcolor--blue">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <th class="small-12 large-12 columns">
              <table>
                <tr>
                  <th class="image--center">
                    <a href="https://www.google.dk/">
                      <img src="http://24.media.tumblr.com/7a40daf7853d830815fb83f79752e94a/tumblr_mz2izkaidT1rfn9zxo4_500.png" alt="test" align="center" class="float-center image--center__inline">
                    </a>
                  </th>
                  <th class="expander"></th>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </th>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <!-- Row 3 -->
      <table class="row collapse bgcolor--content--light">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <th class="small-12 large-12 columns">
              <table>
                <tr>
                  <th class="content">
                    <h3>Headline</h3>
                    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s
                    </p>
                    <br/>
                    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
                    <br/>
                    <p>Best Regards</p>

                    <p>Company Name</p>
                    <br/>
                    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
                    </p>
                    <br/>
                    <a href="#">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing</a>
                  </th>
                  <th class="expander"></th>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </th>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <!-- Row 4 -->
      <!-- HERE THE PROBLEM IS -->
      <table class="row collapse bgcolor">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <th class="small-12 large-6 columns">
              <table>
                <tr>
                  <th class="content">
                    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type
                      specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages,
                      and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
                  </th>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </th>
            <th class="small-12 large-6 columns">
              <table>
                <tr>
                  <th class="content">
                    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type
                      specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages,
                      and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
                  </th>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </th>

            <th class="expander"></th>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>

    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: your p tag is what is aligning it left

Comment: I hope there is some other suggestions. The problem is still not solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add class "content" to table in row 4 as follows:

```
<table class="row collapse bgcolor content">
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. And that is correct syntax to do that etc? My boss has to go through my code tomorrow, so I just want to make sure. I can see that it is working now: [link](http://roulettesuite.com/test.html)[/link] . Then I can set a margin to get space on the right side of the columns?

Comment: Ah no that is gonna make problems to set the content on the row class. The background is not gonna go to full width:

[link](http://roulettesuite.com/test.html)[/link]

Comment: @McDuck4 make html emailings is quite hard. So as far as your template is looking good on the email clients you desire, your code will be correct. Note that it isn't going to be checked by robots on a organic search, but take note that all your styles must be inlined.

Comment: also you can add another table inside the table in "row 4" and add "content" style there

Comment: THank you for the answer again. Do you mean like this: https://jsfiddle.net/huzpfa8a/

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `content` here:

```
<!-- Row 4 -->
        <!-- HERE THE PROBLEM IS -->
        <table class="row collapse bgcolor content">
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I just tried that, but the problem is that the background-color is not gonna go full width then:  [link](http://roulettesuite.com/test.html)[/link]

Comment: add another table inside the table in Row 4, then add content class to child table, not to the parent.

Comment: Thank you for the answer again. Do you mean like this: https://jsfiddle.net/huzpfa8a/